# Working demo for google-text-to-speech Api for Java on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to get a working demo for the google-text-to-speech API under Java/Windows Desktop.

I have created a project in the Google Cloud as described in the Google Cloud manual, activated the Cloud Text-to-Speech API and created a new "Service Account Key". After that I took the sample program provided by Google (QuickstartSample) and put it into IntelliJ (see below) and tried out several other sample programs from Github. I also tried the several examples/hints on stackoverflow.

I use Java SDK 14.0.2, IntelliJ 2020.2.3 and Windows 10 as development environment.

None of the example programs available on the internet seems to work properly.

Can someone please provide a working example program in the above mentioned running environment (Java SDK 14.0.2, IntelliJ 2020.2.3, Windows 10.)?

Any help is highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Code from Google support page (QuickstartSample):

```
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.AudioConfig;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.AudioEncoding;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.SsmlVoiceGender;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.SynthesisInput;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.SynthesizeSpeechResponse;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.VoiceSelectionParams;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Google Cloud TextToSpeech API sample application. Example usage: mvn package exec:java
 * -Dexec.mainClass='com.example.texttospeech.QuickstartSample'
 */
public class QuickstartSample {

  /** Demonstrates using the Text-to-Speech API. */
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
    try (TextToSpeechClient textToSpeechClient = TextToSpeechClient.create()) {
      // Set the text input to be synthesized
      SynthesisInput input = SynthesisInput.newBuilder().setText("Hello, World!").build();

      // Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml voice gender
      // ("neutral")
      VoiceSelectionParams voice =
          VoiceSelectionParams.newBuilder()
              .setLanguageCode("en-US")
              .setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)
              .build();

      // Select the type of audio file you want returned
      AudioConfig audioConfig =
          AudioConfig.newBuilder().setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding.MP3).build();

      // Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected voice parameters and
      // audio file type
      SynthesizeSpeechResponse response =
          textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(input, voice, audioConfig);

      // Get the audio contents from the response
      ByteString audioContents = response.getAudioContent();

      // Write the response to the output file.
      try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.mp3")) {
        out.write(audioContents.toByteArray());
        System.out.println("Audio content written to file \"output.mp3\"");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue can you tell please how have you resolved this. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I haven't resolved it yet